# Can't scroll vertically if touch starts inside AndroidView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm migrating an android app from xml to compose and I'm in a point where I have the following basically:

```
Column (scrollable vertically)
  AndroidView
    Material3 Slider (xml)
```

The problem is that I can scroll the Column if I start the touch anywhere but if I start the touch from the Slider, it will eat all the events and won't let me scroll the Column, only the Slider thumb will scroll (horizontally).

Migrating this component is not an option for now and it would be ideal to just make the scroll work.

So is this possible to make the scroll work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself.

I created a subclass of `ScrollView` and overrode the `canScrollVertically` to always return `true`. Then added the initial contents as a child of it.

```
class ScrollView2(context: Context?, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ScrollView(context, attrs) {
    override fun canScrollVertically(direction: Int): Boolean = true
}
```

Now it works as expected.